# Generic Collection which allows same key

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, collections

Collections like `HashTable` and `Dictionary` don't allow to add a value with the same key but I want to store the same values with the same keys in a `Collection<int,string>`.

Is there a built-in collection which lets me do this?

Comment: You can use `Dictionary<int,IEnumerable<string>>`

Comment: What do you plan to do with it?  Knowing the proper data structure to do has much less to do with what the data is as it does how it's accessed?  Are you constantly getting the values for each key, are you usually performing aggregate operations on all/many values, are you adding/removing elements, if so are they arbitrary, or based on some "start" and/or "end", does the collection need to be ordered, etc.

Comment: Tuple.Item1 is a class with many properties and Tuple.Item2 is a `string` containing "Left", "Right", "Front" or "Back". There can be not more than 10 items in the collection.

Comment: I am basically storing all the `Tuple.Item1` items that have `Tuple.Item2 = "Left"` in a different collection and so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `List<T>` containing a custom class, or even a `List<Tuple<int,string>>`.

```
List<Tuple<int,string>> values = new List<Tuple<int,string>>();

values.Add(Tuple.Create(23, "Foo"));
values.Add(Tuple.Create(23, "Bar"));
```

Alternatively, you can make a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` (or some other collection of string), and populate the values in that way.

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
dict.Add(23, new List<string> { "Foo", "Bar" });
```

This has the advantage of still providing fast lookups by key, while allowing multiple values per key.  However, it's a bit trickier to add values later.  If using this, I'd encapsulate the adding of values in a method, ie:

```
void Add(int key, string value)
{
    List<string> values;
    if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out values))
    {
        values = new List<string>();
        dict[key] = values;
    }

    values.Add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a `List` with a custom `Class`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}

List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
myList.Add(new MyClass { MyInt = 1, MyString = "string" });
```

Comment: Why do you need a built in collection? This essentially is one anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**In short:** The easiest way to go would be a generic `List<T>` collection while skiping the `ArrayList` class. Because, there are some **performance considerations** that you need to take into account.

In addition, you can also use `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>`.
This will store a list of `KeyValuePair` 's that can be duplicate.

In deciding whether to use the `List<T> or ArrayList` class, both of which have similar functionality, remember that the `List<T>` class **performs better** in most cases and is type safe. If a reference type is used for type T of the `List<T>` class, the behavior of the two classes is identical. However, if a value type is used for type T, you need to consider implementation and boxing issues.

As **reference:** you may use the following MSDN article - [List Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Comment: You should basically never be using an `ArrayList` unless you're forced to through interaction with a legacy application.  There may be entirely separate structures that are appropriate, beyond a `List` though. (There isn't enough information to know.)

Comment: Why even mention `ArrayList`.  It's not even an option I consider or present when considering an appropriate data structure.  You use it if you're forced to, and only then.