# The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'ModelsLibrary.Turno' failed because no type converter can convert between these types

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm stumped with this one and your help would be most appreicated.

I get the error:

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'ModelsLibrary.Turno' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.

I pass a dictionary as model to the view and i want to get back the model but the error shows up....

Any ideas?

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(IDictionary<Turno, int> dicionario)
    {
        var turnodocente = new List<TurnoDocente>();

        foreach (var item in dicionario)
        {
            turnodocente.Add(new TurnoDocente
            {
                TurnoId = item.Key.TurnoId,
                DocenteId = item.Value
            });
        }

        HttpResponseMessage responsemeta = await HttpRequestBuilder.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/TurnoDocente", turnodocente);
        responsemeta.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

And the view

```
@model IDictionary<ModelsLibrary.Turno, List<int>>
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Index" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ano Letivo</label>
                <select name="anoLetivo" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Ano"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ano Curricular</label>
                <select name="ano" class="form-control">
                    <option>-Select-</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Semestre</label>
                <select name="semestre" class="form-control">
                    <option>-Select-</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Escolhido" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@if (Model.Count != 0)
{
<form asp-action="Create" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label>Disciplina</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Turno</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Tipologia</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label>Docente</label>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (KeyValuePair<ModelsLibrary.Turno, List<int>> dvp in Model)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => dvp.Key.TurnoId)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => dvp.Key.MetaDisciplina.Nome)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => dvp.Key.LetraTurno)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => dvp.Key.Tipologia.Tipo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="nome" asp-items="ViewBag.Docente"></select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }              
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
}
```

Note: I want to know yet if it's possible to get a parameter from type `Dictionary<Turno, int>` since i pass to the view `Dictionary<Turno, List<int>>`.

Comment: Turno (Student) is a class or object type and cannot be used as dictionary key.. Try using Turno.TurnoId as a key and may be store Turno as a value..

Comment: You said has method parameter or such as on dictionary view model and the parameter?

Comment: Try switching from IDictionary<Turno, int> to IDictionary<int, Turno> in all places..

Comment: But the key needs to be unique in this case the int value needs to came from the selected list option...

Comment: You could have a workaround to allow duplicate key https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146613/generic-collection-which-allows-same-key#comment19591977_14146613

Comment: You might be passing a `IDictionary<Turno, List<int>>` to the view, but your generating form controls with `name` attributes that have no relationship to that model and so will not bind in the POST method. Suggest you start by reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258733/bind-dictionary-with-list-in-viewmodel-to-checkboxes/41560929#41560929) (and stop using a `Dictionary`)